# ASP.net Table won't display item inside "tbody"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been practicing coding in asp.net C# and I think I'm lost here. What i would like to be display is the item inside the table. It's heading is okay, but when i tried to put something inside the body, it won't display any output.

```
<div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>&nbsp; 

                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">TEXT</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">TEXT</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">TEXT</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">TEXT</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrTest">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTest0" Visible="false" Text='<%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnAddRow" CssClass="actionbtnstyle fa fa-plus-square" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnAddRow_Click" Style="font-size: 20px;"></asp:LinkButton>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnDelete" CssClass="actionbtnstyle fa fa-minus-square" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" Style="font-size: 20px;"></asp:LinkButton>

                                            </td>
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtInput1" Text="default" CssClass="form-control" Visible="true"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtInput2" Text="default" CssClass="form-control" Visible="true"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtInput3" Text="default" CssClass="form-control" Visible="true"></asp:TextBox>

                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Does your repeater actually have any content?  What do you see when you go to view source on your web-page after this runs?

Comment: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Repeater-control-Tutorial-with-example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Are you binding repeater to any DataSource?

Comment: you have mixed td with the textbox which is wrong, it wont display until you bound the control with data

Comment: What do you mean with bound the control with data? Should i connect it first with the database? is  that what you mean? @NitinSawant

Comment: yes, you should connect it to db or in memory object

Comment: Thanks for the tips, gonna do it today and give updates. :)